# Dockerized Nginx reverse proxy and Flask app, how to config?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm having trouble deploying a simple Flask app behind a Nginx reverse proxy. The app is the one found at https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/

I'm trying to make the app show up at `subdomain.example.com/flask` but with the current configuration it doesn't work. What i'm missing?

Now my `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ./config/:/etc/nginx/
      - ./ssl-cert/:/etc/ssl/private/
    depends_on:
      - web
    ports:
      - 80:80

  web:
    build:
      context: ./composetest
    expose:
      - 5000

  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

And here's my Nginx's `default.conf`:

```
server {
    listen              80;
    server_name         subdomain.example.com;

    location /flask{
        proxy_pass http://web:5000;
    }

}
```

When i do `docker-compose up --build` i don't get any errors from the Nginx container nor the others (ignoring the production-ready related errors obviously).

Here's what i see when i run the above mentioned command:

```
redis_1       | 1:C 16 May 2021 14:08:42.327 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis_1       | 1:C 16 May 2021 14:08:42.335 # Redis version=6.2.3, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis_1       | 1:C 16 May 2021 14:08:42.335 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
redis_1       | 1:M 16 May 2021 14:08:42.336 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
redis_1       | 1:M 16 May 2021 14:08:42.337 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis_1       | 1:M 16 May 2021 14:08:42.337 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
redis_1       | 1:M 16 May 2021 14:08:42.337 # Server initialized
redis_1       | 1:M 16 May 2021 14:08:42.337 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
redis_1       | 1:M 16 May 2021 14:08:42.338 * Ready to accept connections
web_1         |  * Serving Flask app 'app.py' (lazy loading)
web_1         |  * Environment: production
web_1         |    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
web_1         |    Use a production WSGI server instead.
web_1         |  * Debug mode: off
web_1         |  * Running on all addresses.
web_1         |    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
web_1         |  * Running on http://192.168.112.4:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think everything is fine you exposing port 5000 from your web container and you listing on port 80 for the `nginx` container

you should may foreword  the port 80 to your local machine.

just by adding under depends_on: rebuild test and it should works fine

```
ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Add the subdomain: `subdomain.example.com` also on your local machine under `/etc/hosts`,
if your using `ubuntu` `debian` machine. by adding the host using any text editor `vim` `nano` ...

127.0.0.1   `subdomain.example.com`

Save and Serve from your browser.

Comment: Sorry, i did have the ports in the `docker-compose.yml` but did not copy them over in the post. Your answer helped me anyway because i forgot to forward port 80. I feel like an idiot now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `ports` directive for nginx's service. Even if ports are exposed by an image by default, those do not automatically get bound to the host as in `ports`.

```
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ./config/:/etc/nginx/
      - ./ssl-cert/:/etc/ssl/private/
    depends_on:
      - web
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

After that, you should be able to access nginx at `http://localhost`